# How to Retain Original URLs When Migrating 100 WordPress Posts to BetterDocs Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm in the process of migrating approximately 100 WordPress posts to a custom post type designed specifically for documentation, using the BetterDocs plugin. This plugin mandates that all article URLs include a specific prefix (by default, "/docs/") immediately after the domain. Consequently, the URLs for these articles are structured as follows: [www.mysite.com/docs/post-url/](http://www.mysite.com/docs/post-url/).

For SEO reasons, I prefer not to modify the URLs of these 100 articles. My goal is to maintain the appearance of the articles' original URLs (i.e., [www.mysite.com/post-url/](http://www.mysite.com/post-url/)
) to both search engines and readers, despite the articles being physically located at [www.mysite.com/docs/post-url/](http://www.mysite.com/docs/post-url/).

Is there a workaround or solution that would allow me to achieve this without altering each article's URL? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The best solution is to get in touch with the plugin creator and ask them to remove that part of the slug (it's an easy coding fix) from the custom post creation.  If they won't, you can use a regex redirect to redirect users to the correct URL.